# Full container on Grid System

Tags: html, css, margin

Evening!

I'm currently trying to display a full 100% container wrapped around a grid system however, the full container is still showing with a margin around them.

The full css and html are below:

```
<body>
<div class="container filledBlack">
    <div class="section group">
        <div class="col span_4_of_12 filled matchheight">
            <p>TestLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_4_of_12 filled matchheight">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_4_of_12 filled matchheight">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/matchHeight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $('.matchheight').matchHeight();
    });
    </script>
```

```
/* CONTAINER */
.container{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}

/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
clear: both;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
display: block;
float:left;
margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF TWELVE  */
.span_12_of_12 {
width: 100%;
}

.span_11_of_12 {
width: 91.53%;
}
.span_10_of_12 {
width: 83.06%;
}

.span_9_of_12 {
width: 74.6%;
}

.span_8_of_12 {
width: 66.13%;
}

.span_7_of_12 {
width: 57.66%;
}

.span_6_of_12 {
width: 49.2%;
}

.span_5_of_12 {
width: 40.73%;
}

.span_4_of_12 {
width: 32.26%;
}

.span_3_of_12 {
width: 23.8%;
}

.span_2_of_12 {
width: 15.33%;
}

.span_1_of_12 {
width: 6.866%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }

.span_1_of_12, .span_2_of_12, .span_3_of_12, .span_4_of_12, .span_5_of_12, .span_6_of_12, .span_7_of_12, .span_8_of_12, .span_9_of_12, .span_10_of_12, .span_11_of_12, .span_12_of_12 {
width: 100%; 
}
}
```

Can anyone give me any ideas that would allow me to create the container without messing with the margins/padding etc in the grid? I tried a reset.css but this just threw the grid into disarray.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bro just add to CSS 

`body {
margin: 0px;
}`

```css
/* REMOVE BODY MARGIN */
body {
margin: 0;
}

/* CONTAINER */
.container{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}

/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
clear: both;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
display: block;
float:left;
margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF TWELVE  */
.span_12_of_12 {
width: 100%;
}

.span_11_of_12 {
width: 91.53%;
}
.span_10_of_12 {
width: 83.06%;
}

.span_9_of_12 {
width: 74.6%;
}

.span_8_of_12 {
width: 66.13%;
}

.span_7_of_12 {
width: 57.66%;
}

.span_6_of_12 {
width: 49.2%;
}

.span_5_of_12 {
width: 40.73%;
}

.span_4_of_12 {
width: 32.26%;
}

.span_3_of_12 {
width: 23.8%;
}

.span_2_of_12 {
width: 15.33%;
}

.span_1_of_12 {
width: 6.866%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }

.span_1_of_12, .span_2_of_12, .span_3_of_12, .span_4_of_12, .span_5_of_12, .span_6_of_12, .span_7_of_12, .span_8_of_12, .span_9_of_12, .span_10_of_12, .span_11_of_12, .span_12_of_12 {
width: 100%; 
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container filledBlack">
    <div class="section group">
        <div class="col span_4_of_12 filled matchheight">
            <p>TestLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_4_of_12 filled matchheight">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_4_of_12 filled matchheight">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works at removing the body margin but it also brings the divs within the grid to the edges of the screen which is what i'm trying to avoid. Ideally i'd like a margin to the right and left of the grid which would work with the responsive grid. Could you suggest anything so far as a margin around the container that doesn't interfere with the grid percentages?

Comment: Can you draw what do you what to get? Maybe scheme draw the scheme?

Comment: If you visit this site, they have grid examples: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/layouts/

I would like them to be within a container as they are there while be able to wrap them in full width container. But margin: 0; in the body makes the grid system come to the edges of the browser, i'd like to wrap the main content of the page within a container that is central such as the examples. You can see what the current html and css are doing on my website at www.atlps.co.uk/website

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

And if you want margin on the container

```
.container {
    margin: 0 2%; //or whatever percentage you want
}
```

If you want a centered container that is a specific width, instead just add a max-width and change the margin, and then add some padding to make space between container and content

```
.container {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto; //centering the fixed-width container
    padding: 0 2% //Making space between container edge and content
}
```

I would also suggest that you remove the percentage-based top and bottom margins on your columns, and only add it at the breakpoint where they start stacking. Consider using a fixed value, as vertical margin/padding percentage is calculated by parent **width**, not height (yes it doesn't make much sense to me either).

```
.col {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 1.6%; //here I removed top and bottom margin
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

I can see that you have a s***load of duplicated .col and .container CSS on your online version, you should really remove those. They will be a hassle to deal with once the stylesheet gets more complex

Feel free to elaborate on the issue of I misunderstood anything